# How to end all workers from master in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, node-cluster

I need to end all workers if my db fails to connect...

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    mongoose.connect(config.db.path, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error('Can\'t connect to database')
            // kill all workers here
            process.exit()
            return
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [cluster.disconnect()](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_disconnect_callback)

> Calls .disconnect() on each worker in cluster.workers.
>
> When they are disconnected all internal handles will be closed,
>   allowing the master process to die gracefully if no other event is
>   waiting.
>
> The method takes an optional callback argument which will be called
>   when finished.
>
> This can only be called from the master process.

There is also an optional argument passed to this function - `callback <Function>` which is called when all workers are disconnected and handles are closed.

Answer (score 0):

List all workers by using

cluster.workers

then use cluster.worker.kill() function to end them.